# Class from another namespace not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces

I have recently learned the concepts of namespaces in `PHP` and just want to use them in my `Laravel` project. To do this, I decided to first test what I've learned and created the following codes in my controller and a custom class that I myself created and are as follows :

> app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Classes\UserTables as userTables;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //return view('home');
        $result = new userTables;
        $result->CheckCreate();
    }
}
```

> app\Http\Controllers\Classes\UserTables.class.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Classes\

class UserTables
{
    public function CheckCreate ()
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user_name = Auth::user()->name;
        $table_name = $user_name . '_' . $user_id;
        echo $table_name;
    }
}
```

As I have tested the concept before and it was working properly on the localhost and not in the body of Laravel, I wonder why it now returns the fatal error of :

> FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 27: Class
>   'App\Http\Classes\UserTables' not found
>   1. in HomeController.php line 27

Should I have included and imported the class file before using it and if so what will be the benefit of using namespaces?

Comment: Replace "namespace App\Http\Classes\" with "namespace App\Http\Classes;" and that should be it.

Comment: I am still gaining the same error !!

Comment: You need to rebuild the composer autoload file. `composer dump-autoload`. And `namespace App\Http\Classes\ ` should be `namespace App\Http\Classes`, no slash. Laravel uses PSR-4 autoloading standards. See [here](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Comment: I did both jobs and still getting the same error !!!

Comment: Did you read the autoloading standards? You may wanna read them, the fault is obvious once you do.

Comment: Thank you sir, sorry to bother. Will sure go to solve the problem by studying more.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone especially @Andrew. Studied and used the psr-4 regulations and it is now working very well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues here:
In your Home Controller you have

```
use App\Http\Classes\UserTables as userTables;
```

While UserTable file is saved in 
`app\Http\Controllers\Classes\UserTables.class.php` 
and has namespace

```
namespace App\Http\Classes\;
```

The easiest way to fix this is to change namespace in your UserTables to

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Classes;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try \App\Http\Classes;

as you said it's from another namespace

Answer (score -1):

I guess you probably forgot parentheses:

```
$result = new userTables();
```

Comment: I've tested this before and it still returns error.